# Find the power series representation?

Tags: power-series

$$f(x)=xe^{x^2}$$

$$f(x)= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac1{an!}x^{pn}$$

Need to find $an$ and $pn$?

Not sure how to approach this one, even though I have been solving these type of questions before.

Comment: Do you mean find $a$ and $p$? Finding $an$ and $pn$ makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, a was just suppose to be symbolized by n

Comment: Yes, but your answer is what I needed. In this case a! would be just n!. thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the Taylor Series for $e^x$:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over n!} x^n$$

And when multiplying by $x$ and plugging in $x^2$, we get:

$$xe^{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x\cdot {1\over n!} \left(x^2\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1 \over \frac 1x n!} x^{2n}$$